# PyTest - Passing Argument From Test To Fixture, Having Fixture Return Data

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I've been looking into fixtures for pytest recently as I have a problem writing a test for a scenario.

Basically it's for backend testing. I have a suite of tests that structurally are the same except for what endpoints they hit and then depending on the endpoint there are different fields to verify if they contain certain data or not. This currently works fine individually and I have parameterised tests working for these.

I'm trying to reduce the boiler plate required by using a fixture to do all the heavy lifting.

My issue is I want to pass the name of an endpoint from the test to the fixture and then from the fixture return the data from the endpoint.

Here's what i've tried

```
@pytest.fixture()
def field(request):
    ep_sel
    ep = EndPoint()
    if request.param = 'x':
        ep_sel = ep.endpoint1
    if request.param = 'y':
        ep_sel = ep.endpoint2

    return ep_sel


@pytest.mark.parametrize('field', [('x'), ('y')])
def test_intgra_002_basisgruppe_req_fields_links(field)
    main.entity_check(data, field, endpoint_name, True)
```

I need to be able to call the endpoint from the test as well as set what fields need to be tested from the returned data.

Comment: But where does the `endpoint_name` come from in your example?

Comment: @hoefling That class is initialised in the test file (not shown in the example) I will be initialising it in the fixture for my complete version once I get over the above problem.

Comment: I see. Although I don't quite understand the whole picture, I think what you're looking for is the [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources). If the fixture is named `field`, `@pytest.mark.parametrize('field', [('x'), ('y')], indirect=True)` will first pass `x` to the `field` fixture and then pass fixture's return value to the test.